# Magento 2 get categories graphql fails with "There is no attribute class assigned to field categoryList"

Tags: magento2, category, graphql

Request:

```
query {
  categories {
    items {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

Error Response:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "debugMessage": "There is no attribute class assigned to field categoryList",
      "message": "Internal server error",
      "extensions": {
        "category": "internal"
      },
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "categories"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "categories": null
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This Query**

```
{
  categories(
    filters: {
      ids: {in: ["3", "9", "12", "21", "38", "39"]}
      parent_id: {in: ["2"]}
    }
    pageSize:3
    currentPage: 2
  ) {
    total_count
    items {
      uid
      level
      name
      path
      children_count
      children {
        uid
        level
        name
        path
        children_count
        children {
          uid
          level
          name
          path
        }
      }
    }
    page_info {
      current_page
      page_size
      total_pages
    }
  }
}
```

**The categories query returns a list of categories that match the specified filter. You must add a filter to the query. This query differs from the categoryList query in that it supports pagination.**

[For More Click Here](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/graphql/schema/products/queries/categories/)